# More DRY way of conditionally filling variables?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a chart component and it behaves differently if `data` has been passed in or not.

Here are two ways I can think of to conditionally fill chart variables.
(`data` will be empty `{}` or have non-empty values)

```javascript
// helper
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
  for (const i in obj) return false;
  return true;
}
```

```javascript
const gridInterval = 5;

let yTopTickValue;
let yBottomTickValue;
let yTickCount;
let xTopTickValue;
let xBottomTickValue;
let xTickCount;

if (!isEmptyObject(data)) {
  yTopTickValue = Math.ceil(data.yMax / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
  yBottomTickValue = Math.floor(data.yMin / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
  yTickCount = (yTopTickValue - yBottomTickValue) / gridInterval + 1;

  xTopTickValue = Math.ceil(data.yMax / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
  xBottomTickValue = Math.floor(data.yMin / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
  xTickCount = (xTopTickValue - xBottomTickValue) / gridInterval + 1;
}
```

and

```javascript
const gridInterval = 5;
const isDataEmpty = isEmptyObject(data);

const yTopTickValue = isDataEmpty ? null: Math.ceil(data.yMax / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
const yBottomTickValue = isDataEmpty ? null: Math.floor(data.yMin / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
const yTickCount = isDataEmpty ? null: (yTopTickValue - yBottomTickValue) / gridInterval + 1;

const xTopTickValue = isDataEmpty ? null: Math.ceil(data.yMax / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
const xBottomTickValue = isDataEmpty ? null: Math.floor(data.yMin / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
const xTickCount = isDataEmpty ? null: (xTopTickValue - xBottomTickValue) / gridInterval + 1;
```

Are there any other clever versions I'm missing?

Comment: "Clever" and more DRY, I can think of one, maybe (an object of functions), but it would be notably harder to understand at a glance. I prefer your current approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @CertainPerformance. I've settled on using the first for readability but am on the hunt for a readable and DRY version. Not that there has to be one. 

Comment: @BCdotWEB done. Thanks. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @CertainPerformance's feedback, here is where I landed.
This is the most DRY version possible.

```javascript
const chartSettings = (gridInterval, data) => {
  if (isEmptyObject(data)) return;

  const ticks = {
    yTopTick: Math.ceil(+data.yMax / gridInterval) * gridInterval,
    yBottomTick: Math.floor(+data.yMin / gridInterval) * gridInterval,
    xTopTick: Math.ceil(+data.yMax / gridInterval) * gridInterval,
    xBottomTick: Math.floor(+data.yMin / gridInterval) * gridInterval,
  };

  return {
    ...ticks,
    yTickCount: 1 + (ticks.yTopTick - ticks.yBottomTick) / gridInterval,
    xTickCount: 1 + (ticks.xTopTick - ticks.xBottomTick) / gridInterval,
  };
};
```

Comment: While OPs are [encouraged to answer their own questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) bear in mind that ["_Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted._"](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)...

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ, I'm not exactly sure what else to add to this answer to make if fit better. It seems to have the context necessary by pointing to CertainPerformance's answer. I want to be a good codereview citizen. If you could give specific feedback it would help me going forward. Thanks! 

Comment: Please see the Help Center page [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) - the section **I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?**. It appears you have already taken option #2 - so bear in mind "_Your answer must meet the standards of a Code Review answer, just like any other answer. **Describe what you changed, and why** [Code-only answers that don't actually review the code are insufficient](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/120114) and are subject to deletion._"

Comment: ok, based on all those links it looks like my answer meets the criteria. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a reasonable number of variables that all relate to one particular thing (chart settings), rather than having lots of standalone variables, you might consider using a single object instead. Regardless of any other issues with the code, I'd consider a single object to be slightly more appropriate than multiple similar standalone variables regardless.

Using a single object can also let you exploit a shortcut: if `data` doesn't exist, just use an empty object. Otherwise, type out the object literal using your formulas:

```
const getChartSettings = (gridInterval, data) => {
  if (isEmptyObject(data)) {
    return {};
  }
  const yTopTickValue = Math.ceil(data.yMax / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
  const yBottomTickValue = Math.floor(data.yMin / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
  const xTopTickValue = Math.ceil(data.yMax / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
  const xBottomTickValue = Math.floor(data.yMin / gridInterval) * gridInterval;
  return {
    yTopTickValue,
    yBottomTickValue,
    yTickCount : (chartSettings.yTopTickValue - chartSettings.yBottomTickValue) / gridInterval + 1,
    xTopTickValue,
    xBottomTickValue,
    xTickCount : (chartSettings.xTopTickValue - chartSettings.xBottomTickValue) / gridInterval + 1,
  };
};
```

Then you can call the function, reference `chartSettings.yBottomTickValue`, and either get a number or `undefined`.

YMMV on whether that's worth using or not.

It's unfortunate that the `TickCount`s depend on the prior calculated values - if they didn't, it could be made to look a lot simpler by just returning the single object literal instead of defining variables beforehand.

You could still return an object alone without prior defined variables by making the TickCounts *getters* instead, but that'd be weird-looking, I wouldn't use it:

```
return {
  yTopTickValue: Math.ceil(data.yMax / gridInterval) * gridInterval,
  yBottomTickValue: Math.floor(data.yMin / gridInterval) * gridInterval,
  get yTickCount() {
    return (this.yTopTickValue - this.yBottomTickValue) / gridInterval + 1;
  },
  // ...
```

**Operator position** You also might consider putting the `+ 1` at the beginning, rather than at the end, eg:

```
xTickCount : 1 + (chartSettings.xTopTickValue - chartSettings.xBottomTickValue) / gridInterval,
```

I think that's a bit clearer than putting it right next to the `/ gridInterval`. You could also consider using [`no-mixed-operators`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-mixed-operators).

Comment: Hi @CertainPerformance. Thanks again for the help! `+1` You set me on a path that lead to a solution I really like. It's basically your first option with some spread magic.